# Change the number size, of input type="number"

Tags: html, css

I read a lot about changing the size, but all the options, affects the size of the input box.

I have this

```css
input[type="number"] {
width:5rem;
font-size:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="introData">
  <label for="introData" class="label">Introducir los segundos que se mostrará cada palabra</label>
  <input type="number" name="introData" id="inputData" style="font-size: 10px;"></input>

  <button id="start" type="submit" class="btn">
    start
  </button>
</div>
```

I used:

- size="5" inside the HTML tag (X)
- placeholder="10"(X)
- style="font-size: 10px;" )(X)

*x = did not work

This

> input[type="number"] {
> width:20%; as well rem,em,px, etc
> }

All options I read and test change the size of the box. This question could seem duplicated, but all the answers I saw didn't solve my problem. :( Thanks :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? To have a small number in a tall input box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `style="font-size: 10px;"` as an attribute in that `input` tag in your HTML. Inline styles overwrite external CSS. Just erase that and it works as desired:

```css
input[type="number"] {
width:5rem;
font-size:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="introData">
  <label for="introData" class="label">Introducir los segundos que se mostrará cada palabra</label>
  <input type="number" name="introData" id="inputData">

  <button id="start" type="submit" class="btn">
    start
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: The HTML tag was an example, my fault for not deleting it. I do not what I was doing wrong, ahhh, but, it works, thank you very much.